# What's wrong with my recursive list construction?

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I've simplified the functions in question. I'm having trouble constructing a list inside a monad. I suspect a precedence problem.

```
newtype Boundary = MkBoundary Integer

testFunc :: [Boundary] -> [Maybe Integer]
testFunc (MkBoundary x:xs)
   | (even x) = Just x : testFunc xs
   | otherwise = Nothing : testFunc xs
testFunc _ = []
```

This works as expected. But I need to work in a monad. I'll use IO for this example

```
testFunc :: [Boundary] -> IO [Maybe Integer]
testFunc (MkBoundary x:xs)
   | (even x) = return $ Just x : testFunc xs
   | otherwise = return $ Nothing : testFunc xs
testFunc _ = []
```

No matter how I try to manipulate precedence, this breaks.

```
test.hs:6:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Maybe Integer]'
                with actual type `IO [Maybe Integer]'
    In the return type of a call of `testFunc'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `testFunc xs'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `Just x : testFunc xs'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What I am trying to accomplish is a constructing a list, then returning it to IO. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `testFunc xs` returns an `IO [Maybe Integer]`, and you are using it as the tail of a list as if it were a `[Maybe Integer]`.  You need to extract:

```
| (even x) = do
    xs' <- testFunc xs
    -- now xs' is of type [Maybe Integer]
    return $ Just x : xs'
```

Or, a more succinct way of saying the same thing:

```
| (even x) = (Just x :) <$> testFunc xs
```

(`(<$>)` is from `Control.Applicative` and has type

```
(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

specialized to `IO` .  It applies a function to the value "inside" a monadic computation.)

Oh, also what missingno said :-)

Answer (score 4):

luqui answered your question, I will note a useful combinator.

If you want to perform a monadic action for all elements of a list, use "mapM". It is defined as:

```
 mapM f [] = return []
 mapM f (x:xs) = do y <- f x
                    ys <- mapM f xs
                    return (y:ys)
```

or something equivalent. [If you know some other combinators, you can write `mapM` with `liftM2` and `foldr`.]

```
 testFunc = mapM f
     where f (MkBoundary x) | even x = do print x
                                          return $ Just x
                            | otherwise = return Nothing
```

test in GHCi:

```
*Main> testFunc [MkBoundary 2, MkBoundary 3, MkBoundary 4]
2
4
[Just 2,Nothing,Just 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to change the second case

```
test_func _ = return []
           -- ^^^^^^
```

---

Also, I think your example function could be more clearly written as

```
test_func :: [Boundary] -> [Maybe Integer]
test_func = ...

monadic_test_func = [Boundary] -> IO [Maybe Integer]
monadic_test_func = return . test_func
```

This keeps the pure code separated from the nasty monad stuff. It also saves you from having to type "return" thrice! :)

---

And finally, why are you creating such a function in the first place? The monad part (at least in your example) seems to be somewhat unrelated to the main function logic (since you are just doing a `return`).

Perhaps you use some nice library functions to keep your function pure and untouched?

```
--instead of 
monadic_value >>= monadic_test_func

--use
fmap test_func monadic_value
-- or equivalently
test_func <$> monadic_value
liftM test_func monadic_value
```

Comment: He said he has simplified the functions in question.  It's possible he needs to do I/O from within this function somewhere.  And learning how to convert pure code to monadic code is a valuable skill in any case.

Comment: Oh but I can also see how he might have a misconception that he needs to rewrite his perfectly good pure function if he needs to use it from within a monad, in which case this answer is on the right track.

Comment: @luqui - I do indeed have that misconception. I don't know where it came from. I'm supposed to know better. Early on in my project I fixed a mess of problems by putting my return type in a certain monad, whereas I should have been using fmap or liftM all along. I imagine there will be some problems in getting things right, and I'll be bringing it to this forum soon enough.